# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jredis/JRedis

Tags: spring-mvc, redis

I have following configuration xml for redis

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Redis Connection Factory -->
    <bean id="jredisConnectionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jredis.JredisConnectionFactory"
        p:use-pool="true" p:host-name="server" p:port="6379" />

    <!-- Redis Template Configuration -->
    <bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate"
        p:connection-factory-ref="jredisConnectionFactory" />

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.hhl.main" />
    <context:spring-configured />

</beans>
```

I have following maven dependency added

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/redis.clients/jedis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-redis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

**I get following error.**

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jredis/JRedis     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_66]  at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:572)
>   ~[spring-core-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489)
>   ~[spring-core-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:475)
>   ~[spring-core-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:241)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1063)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1036)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:759)
>   ~[spring-context-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>   ~[spring-context-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:434)
>   ~[spring-web-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>   [spring-web-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>   [spring-web-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.62]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.62]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.62]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.62]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.62]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_66]
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [?:1.8.0_66]  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [?:1.8.0_66]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_66]
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jredis.JRedis    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
>   ~[catalina.jar:7.0.62]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
>   ~[catalina.jar:7.0.62]    ... 30 more Jun 23, 2016 12:15:12 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart SEVERE:
>   Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of
>   class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Comment: You defined a **jredisConnectionFactory** and you are trying to use **jedisConnFactory**?

Comment: Did you do a correct clean install with maven ?

Comment: My problem solved by replace class org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jredis.JredisConnectionFactory   with org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory                                                                                                                        **Thanks for help**